# launchmode of Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, launchmode, android-task

Suppose I have a task in which I have `A, B & C` `Activities` respectively. And then I'm starting a new Activity D which has singleInstance as it's launchMode.

Now, I wonder what happens in the task level? Will the same task be preserved but contains only `Activity D` or new task is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new task will be created with the single `Activity D`. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes):

*Same as "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always the single and only member of its task.*

So you'll get

```
Task 1: A,B,C
Task 2: D
```

The following two sequence are correct which confirms the docs:

1. A -> B -> C -> D -> back -> C -> back -> B -> back -> A -> back -> Home Screen (HS)
2. A -> B -> C -> D -> HS -> calling your task from recent apps -> D -> back -> HS

Comment: We also take the taskAffinity property into consideration as well. If the affinities are the same then no new task will be created.